# use mathematical induction to show that $n^3 + 5n$ is divisible by $3$ for all $n\ge1$

Tags: calculus, induction

What I have so far

Base: $n^3 + 5n$

Let $n=1$

$$
1^3 + 5(1) = 6
$$

$6$ is divisible by $3$

Induction step: $(k+1)^3 + 5(k+1)$

$(k^3 + 3k^2 + 8k + 6)$ is divisible by $3$

I kind of get lost after this point. For starters, how do I prove that this isn't applicable for any number less than $1$? Also, where do I go after this? Thank you!

Comment: Induction is used to prove a fact over the natural numbers, so if you use induction your goal is not to prove it for n < 1, but your goal is also not to disprove it isn‘t applicable to n < 1

Comment: If you know modular arithmetic, it's $\equiv n(n+1)(n-1)\pmod3$

Comment: Do you know any **algebra**?  In particular that (k+ 1)^3= k^3+ 3k^3+ 3k+ 1?  With that (k+1)^3+ 5(k+ 1)= k^3+ 3k^2+ 3k+ 1+ 5k+ 5= k^3+ 3k^2+ 8k+ 6= k^3+ 5k+ (3k^3+ 3k+6)=  k^3+ 5k+ 3(k^3+ k+ 2).  And as JaMoin pointed out, the problem asks you to prove the statement is true for $n\ge 1$.  It does NOT say anything about what happens when n< 1.

Answer (score 2):

In the induction step, we assume that it holds for $n = k$.

That means that $\exists a \in \mathbb{Z} : k^3 + 5k = 3a$.

Then, for $(k+1)$, we get
$$
\begin{split}
(k+1)^3 + 5(k+1)
 &= k^3 + 3k^2 + 8k + 6 \\
 &= (k^3 + 5k) + 3k^2 + 3k + 6 \\
 &= 3a + 3k^2 + 3k + 6 \\
 &= 3(a + k^2 + k + 2).
\end{split}
$$
So, if $k^3 + 5k$ is a multiple of $3$, then $(k+1)^3 + 5(k+1)$ must also be a multiple of $3$.

Comment: +1 nice use of the inductive hypothesis

Answer (score 2):

Just note that
$$
f(n+1)-f(n)=(n+1)^3 + 5(n+1)-(n^3 + 5n)=3 (n^2 + n + 2)
$$
I suspect this is the intended solution.

Actually, no induction is needed:
$$
n^3 + 5n = 6 \binom{n}{1} + 6 \binom{n}{2} + 6 \binom{n}{3}
$$
and so is always a multiple of $6$.

Answer (score 1):

You could be better to take the difference of successive terms as follows:

$$(n+1)^3+5(n+1)-n^3-5n= 3n^2+3n+1+5=3(n^2+n+2)$$ which is clearly a multiple of three. It follows that if $n^3+5n$ is divisible by $3$, so is $(n+1)^3+5(n+1)$, which is what you need for your inductive step.

Notice how taking the difference here immediately eliminates the highest order term in the each of the polynomial expressions - so $n^3$ disappears as does the $5n$ term. This is typical for such polynomial cases, and can leave you working with simpler expressions.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

$$
\begin{split}
k^3 + 3k^2+8k+6
 &= 3(k^2+3k+2) + k^3-k \\
 &= 3(k^2+3k+2) + k(k^2-1) \\
 &= 3(k^2+3k+2) + k(k-1)(k+1)
\end{split}
$$

Comment: That is not a proof by induction, though.

Comment: @RobbytheBelgian it does work in the inductive framework -- after all if you can prove the inductive step without relying on the inductive hypothesis, it's also proof, but is less instructive...

Comment: Fair enough ...

Answer (score -1):

You correctly expanded $(k+1)^3+5(k+1)$ into $k^3+3k^2+8k+6$. What you now need to do is to *show* that $k^3+3k^2+8k+6$ is divisible by $3$, using the *inductive hypothesis* that $k^3+5k$ is divisible by $3$. To do this, simply write

$$k^3+3k^2+8k+6=(k^3+5k)+3k^2+3k+6$$

and note that each of the four terms on the right hand side is divisible by $3$.

As for your question,  how do I prove that this isn't applicable for any number less than $1$?, you don't need to prove *anything* about numbers less than $1$ (and in this case the assertion does still hold: $n^3+5n$ is divisible by $3$ for *all* integers $n$, positive or negative). Induction only needs to go in one direction.